# Conditional numpy.cumsum?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gis, cumsum

I'm very new to python and numpy, so sorry if I misuse some terminology.

I have converted a raster to a 2D numpy array in the hopes of doing calculations on it quickly and efficiently.

- I need to get the cumulative sum across a numpy array such that, for
  each value, I generate the sum of all values that are less than or
  equal to that, and write that value to a new array.  I need to cycle
  through the entire array that way.
- I also need to scale the output between 1 and 100, but that seems
  more straightforward.

Attempt to clarify by example:

```
array([[ 4,  1  ,  3   ,  2] dtype=float32)
```

I would want the output values (just doing first row by hand) to read:

```
array([[ 10,  1  ,  6   ,  3], etc.
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

---

The near finished script for anyone who's interested:

```
#Generate Cumulative Thresholds
#5/15/14

import os
import sys
import arcpy
import numpy as np

#Enable overwriting output data
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

#Set working directory
os.chdir("E:/NSF Project/Salamander_Data/Continuous_Rasters/Canadian_GCM/2020/A2A/")

#Set geoprocessing variables
inRaster = "zero_eurycea_cirrigera_CA2A2020.tif"
des = arcpy.Describe(inRaster)
sr = des.SpatialReference
ext = des.Extent
ll = arcpy.Point(ext.XMin,ext.YMin)

#Convert GeoTIFF to numpy array
a = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(inRaster)

#Flatten for calculations
a.flatten()

#Find unique values, and record their indices to a separate object
a_unq, a_inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)

#Count occurences of array indices
a_cnt = np.bincount(a_inv)

#Cumulatively sum the unique values multiplied by the number of
#occurences, arrange sums as initial array
b = np.cumsum(a_unq * a_cnt)[a_inv]

#Divide all values by 10 (reverses earlier multiplication done to
#facilitate accurate translation of ASCII scientific notation
#values < 1 to array)
b /= 10

#Rescale values between 1 and 100
maxval = np.amax(b)
b /= maxval
b *= 100

#Restore flattened array to shape of initial array
c = b.reshape(a.shape)

#Convert the array back to raster format
outRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(c,ll,des.meanCellWidth,des.meanCellHeight)

#Set output projection to match input
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(outRaster, sr)

#Save the raster as a TIFF
outRaster.save("C:/Users/mkcarte2/Desktop/TestData/outRaster.tif")

sys.exit()
```

Comment: Could you give an example on e.g. a small 1D or 2D array of what you would expect as the output? As your question is currently, it is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question would be clearer if you provide a simple input and desired output.

Comment: It's still not particularly clear, since your example data is sorted. What should happen for `array([[4, 1], [3, 2]])`?

Comment: Ah! You're right.  I went off your example this time.

Comment: There is an extra square bracket in your example.  Is your input actually 1D or 2D?

Comment: @Vergentorix How does `[4, 1, 3, 2]` become `[10, 1, 6, 3]`? I don't see the pattern there.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser It's a raster so i assume the real data would be 2D

Comment: Correct, it's 2D. The pattern is: for each value, sum all values over entire array that are less than or equal it.  Write those values to a new array.

Comment: something like `[sum(x for x in arr if x <= a) for a in arr]` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle repeats, this could work:

```
In [40]: a
Out[40]: array([4, 4, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2])

In [41]: a_unq, a_inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)

In [42]: a_cnt = np.bincount(a_inv)

In [44]: np.cumsum(a_unq * a_cnt)[a_inv]
Out[44]: array([20, 20,  6,  2,  0, 12, 12,  2,  0,  6], dtype=int64)
```

Where of course `a` is your array flattened, that you would then have to reshape to the original shape.

---

And of course once numpy 1.9 is out, you can condense lines 41 and 42 above into the single, faster:

```
a_unq, a_inv, a_cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: Heh, I *just* worked out exactly the same answer.  Figures @Jaime, the master of `np.unique`, would get there first.

Comment: I have a feeling that this a little cleaner and more efficient than my master-piece :).

Comment: Very nice code. I'm still working out whether I can successfully run it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your exact code, and the full traceback of the error somewhere? I have just rerun the code above and haven't seen any issue, can you double check there is no typo or missing parenthesis in your code?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

This is ugly, but I think it finally works:

```
import numpy as np

def cond_cum_sum(my_array):
    my_list = []
    prev = -np.inf
    prev_sum = 0
    for ele in my_array:
        if prev != ele:
            prev_sum += ele
        my_list.append(prev_sum)
        prev = ele
    return np.array(my_list)

a = np.array([[4,2,2,3],
              [9,0,5,2]], dtype=np.float32)

flat_a = a.flatten()
flat_a.sort() 

temp = np.argsort(a.ravel())   

cum_sums = cond_cum_sum(flat_a)

result_1 = np.zeros(len(flat_a))
result_1[temp] = cum_sums

result = result_1.reshape(a.shape)
```

Result:

```
>>> result
array([[  9.,   2.,   2.,   5.],
       [ 23.,   0.,  14.,   2.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I believe my example was misleading, since I arbitrarily ranked the data.  The actual data would not be ranked.

Comment: @Akavall Thought along the same lines, but i think this fails if any values are equal.

Comment: @M4rtini, Yes it does not work if any values are equal. If I can't come up with something fast I'll delete my answer.

Comment: shouldn't it be `[11, 4, 4, 7]`? or did I missed the part where only unique values must be summed?

Comment: @njzk2, Where did OP say that only unique values must be summed? My understanding was that each value would be only added once.

Comment: @Akavall: my formulation is wrong, but my meaning is the same as yours. I don't see where each value must be added only once.

Comment: @njzk2, we only add if the next value is larger, so `[0,2,2,3]` would be `[0,2,2,5]`, we don't add the second `2` because it is not larger than the previous value.

Comment: @Akavall: I read `all values that are less than or equal to`. One way or the other, my feeling is that this question lacks precision and leaves to much room for interpretation

Comment: @njzk2, I totally agree about lack of precision, which is a shame because this is an interesting question no matter how duplicates are handled.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision.  Essentially, what I'm trying to do is sum all values across the entire raster (which has been converted to a 2D array) that are less than or equal to the value/pixel in question.  Whether or not they are unique values.  I hope that clarifies it.

I then need to scale all the values between 1 and 100, but that's a different question.

Comment: @Vergentorix, I still don't think that I am clear. Can you provide a small complete example of your input and desired output? Providing a small example is generally a good idea; it helps people understand your question better.

Answer (score 1):

With less numpy and more python:

```
a = np.array([[4,2,2,3],
              [9,0,5,2]], dtype=np.float32)

np.array([[sum(x for x in arr if x <= subarr) for subarr in arr] for arr in a])
# array([[ 11.,   4.,   4.,   7.],
#        [ 16.,   0.,   7.,   2.]])
```

If the sum only considers items once no matter how much they appear, then,

```
np.array([[sum(set(x for x in arr if x <= subarr)) for subarr in arr] for arr in a]) 
# array([[  9.,   2.,   2.,   5.],
#        [ 16.,   0.,   7.,   2.]])
```

Comment: My understanding (maybe incorrect) was that OP was interested in `cumsum` over the entire array, not the rows separately.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
a=np.array([ 4,  1  ,  3   ,  2])

np.array([np.sum(a[a<=x])for x in a])
```

Gives

```
array([10,  1,  6,  3])
```

---

For a 2D array (assuming you want the sum of the whole array, not just the row):

```
a=np.array([[ 4,  1  ,  3   ,  2],[ 5,  1  ,  3   ,  2]])

np.array([[np.sum(a[a<=x])for x in a[y,:]]for y in range(a.shape[0])])
```

Gvies

```
array([[16,  2, 12,  6],
       [21,  2, 12,  6]])
```