# Most Pythonic way of assigning values of array to another array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, unique

I have two arrays with the same length (6, in this example). One stores `floats`:

```
a = np.array([0.2, 0.01, 0.5, 0.7, 0., 0.002])
```

the second one stores indices (hence, `int` values):

```
indices = np.array([4, 9, 0, 2, 2, 4])
```

In my code I initialize another array, which has length in general different from that of `a` and `indices`, for example 10 in this example:

```
c = np.zeros(10)
```

I would like to find a Pythonic way to accomplish the following:

```
for i in range(len(indices)):
    c[indices[i]] += a[i]
```

which, in this example, produces:

```
[0.5   0.    0.7   0.    0.202 0.    0.    0.    0.    0.01 ]
```

I tried looking at [this brilliant example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662704/conditional-numpy-cumsum), however I am not sure how this can be applied here.

Comment: `indices = np.array([4, `**9**`, 0, 2, 2, 4])` ... `a` does not have ten items.

Comment: @wwii look carefully, it's `a[i]`, ot `a[indices[i]]`, check out my answer, `numpy` ufuncs have something for this exact use-case, the `.at` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.at` method of the `np.add` ufunc:

```
np.add.at(c, indices, a)
```

Here's the `help` page for the `.at` method of ufuncs:

```
at(...) method of numpy.ufunc instance
    at(a, indices, b=None, /)

    Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand 'a' for elements
    specified by 'indices'. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to
    ``a[indices] += b``, except that results are accumulated for elements that
    are indexed more than once. For example, ``a[[0,0]] += 1`` will only
    increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas
    ``add.at(a, [0,0], 1)`` will increment the first element twice.

    .. versionadded:: 1.8.0

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        The array to perform in place operation on.
    indices : array_like or tuple
        Array like index object or slice object for indexing into first
        operand. If first operand has multiple dimensions, indices can be a
        tuple of array like index objects or slice objects.
    b : array_like
        Second operand for ufuncs requiring two operands. Operand must be
        broadcastable over first operand after indexing or slicing.
```

Answer (score 1):

For `sum`, your operation is exactly what `bincount` is:

```
np.bincount(indices, weights=a)
```

Output:

```
array([0.5  , 0.   , 0.7  , 0.   , 0.202, 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ,  0.01 ])
```

Comment: Needs `minlength` but should otherwise work for sum